# NullReferenceException when assigning property of array item

Tags: c#, arrays

I want to create an array of my class Word. Here is the code:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Word[] Wörter = new Word[5];
        Wörter[0]._Word_ = "Hallo";
        Wörter[1]._Word_ = "Flugzeug";
        Wörter[2]._Word_ = "Automobil";
        Wörter[3]._Word_ = "Musikanlage";
        Wörter[4]._Word_ = "Steuerung";


    }

 public class Word
    {
        private string _Word;
        private int _counter;

        public string _Word_
        {
            get
            {
                return _Word;
            }
            set
            {
                _Word = value; 
            }

        }

        public int _counter_
        {
            get
            {
                return _counter;
            }
            set
            {
                _counter = 0;
            }
        }
    }
```

I always get a System.NullReferenceException in this line

```
Wörter[0]._Word_ = "Hallo";
```

If I call the an instance of my class(without array), everything works fine. I think I got a problem with the array. Maybe is using an array in this situation not the best think to do. Thank you for helping!

Comment: look into Lists -  a `List<Word>` will likely do quite nicely.

Comment: I am not sure what you are expecting. You have to create the instances somewhere, i.e. `new Word()`. See [What is a NullReferenceException and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4660142/238902) for more info

Comment: See duplicate's answer, section 'Array Elements'.

Comment: What is with the properties being surrounded with underscores? My eyes don't know what to do with this.

Comment: @DrewKennedy I don't often create classes with properties but I heard that you should avoid using public properties - Maybe the convention is wrong but that's just for testing things..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you're creating an array, but that array contains empty references to start with - you're never creating any instances of `Word`. You want something like:

```
Word[] Wörter = new Word[5];
Wörter[0] = new Word();
Wörter[0]._Word_ = "Hallo";
// etc
```

However, you can reduce the code to achieve the same effect using *object initializers*:

```
Word[] Wörter = new Word[5];
Wörter[0] = new Word { _Word_ = "Hallo" };
...
```

And then you can use an array initializer to do the whole thing in one statement:

```
Word[] Wörter =
{
    new Word { _Word = "Hallo" },
    new Word { _Word_ = "Flugzeug" },
    new Word { _Word_ = "Automobil" },
    new Word { _Word_ = "Musikanlage" },
    new Word { _Word_ = "Steuerung"}
};
```

The next step in my view would be to start following .NET naming conventions, calling your properties `Text` and `Counter` (you can't call the property `Word` as that's the name of the class), using automatically implemented properties to reduce cruft further, and then adding a constructor taking the initial value of the property in the constructor:

```
public class Word
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public int Counter { get; set; }

    public Word(string text)
    {
        Text = text;
    }
}

Word[] words =
{
    new Word("Hallo"),
    new Word("Flugzeug"),
    new Word("Automobil"),
    new Word("Musikanlage" )
    new Word("Steuerung")
};
```

Doesn't that look better? :)

You might also want to make the `Text` property read-only. Until C# 6 lands that means either keeping a private setter or using a "manually implemented" property, but in C# 6 you'll be able to write:

```
public string Text { get; }
```

and just assign it in the constructor.

Additionally, you need to think about whether you really need an array at all. Often using a `List<T>` offers significantly more flexibility.

Comment: Ah yes...damn sometimes I forget those obviously things. Thank your for the answer! :)

Comment: @avbmath: See all the rest of the answer for further suggestions.

Comment: Wow the array initializer really looks nice! I will try it

Answer (score 5):

You only istantiate the array but not the elements

```
Word[] Wörter = new Word[5];
Wörter[0] = new Word { _Word_ = "Hallo" };
```

and so on...

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
   Word[] Wörter = new Word[5];

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        Wörter[i] = new Word();

    Wörter[0]._Word_ = "Hallo";
    Wörter[1]._Word_ = "Flugzeug";
    Wörter[2]._Word_ = "Automobil";
    Wörter[3]._Word_ = "Musikanlage";
    Wörter[4]._Word_ = "Steuerung";
```

Comment: I think thats the best way for long arrays. Thank you!

Comment: @avbmath: I don't think it's cleaner than using an array initializer... see the options in my answer.